# Make stacked area chart overlapping area

Tags: d3.js

[This stacked area](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3020685) chart by Mike Bostock appears slightly misleading to me. For example, if you look at the numbers on the yAxis, it appears (to me) that for Monday 23, the lightest blue area has a total of approximately 95 or 96, but if you look at the data, the total for light blue (which is actually group 3) is really 46 for Monday 23. So why is that? because the areas are stacked ontop of each other, wheras the yAxis gives the impression (in my opinion), for example, that the area at the top of the stack includes all the numbers below it (hence my reading of 96 for group 3 on Monday January 23).

My question is, how can that graph (code and data below) be changed so the it works the way that I initially interpreted it, so that the raw data for any area that's ontop includes the totals below. Likely not the correct term for it, but I want to make a stacked area chart "overlapping" instead.

```
var format = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%y");

var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var z = d3.scale.category20c();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(d3.time.days);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var stack = d3.layout.stack()
    .offset("zero")
    .values(function(d) { return d.values; })
    .x(function(d) { return d.date; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.value; });

var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.key; });

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("cardinal")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(function(d) { return y(d.y0); })
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = format.parse(d.date);
    d.value = +d.value;
  });

  var layers = stack(nest.entries(data));

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);

  svg.selectAll(".layer")
      .data(layers)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "layer")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d.values); })
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); });

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);
});
```

**data**

```
key,value,date
Group1,37,04/23/12
Group2,12,04/23/12
Group3,46,04/23/12
Group1,32,04/24/12
Group2,19,04/24/12
Group3,42,04/24/12
Group1,45,04/25/12
Group2,16,04/25/12
Group3,44,04/25/12
Group1,24,04/26/12
Group2,52,04/26/12
Group3,64,04/26/12
```

Comment: So you want an [area chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883195)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yes, but with the ability to show multiple areas in one chart, which requires (I suppose) lines at the top bounds of each area to clearly mark the area, and then different tinting to color each area. Similar to what I linked to, but as you can see in the demo that I linked to, the yAxis labels are misleading because each area doesn't start from the bottom. Rather the zero value for each area starts directly ontop of the one below it.

Comment: I don't see the problem to be honest -- can't you just draw several `path`s for the different areas?

Comment: Look at this example (from a library) http://c3js.org/samples/chart_area_stacked.html  when the value of blue is less than the value of the orange area, it is lower than it on the chart. That doesn't happen in the example I linked to in the OP. I'm trying to make the example I linked to in the OP like that i.e. when the values are the same in the areas there will be intersection

Comment: The lines in the C3 example only intersect because of the line interpolation. For what you want (as far as I can tell), you would simply draw the separate areas without caring much about that they'll be shown together.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff but that's exactly the point of my question, how (in the graph I linked to in the OP) do I "simply draw the separate areas without caring that they'll be shown together i.e. overlap)" rather than keeping the areas separate.

Comment: See e.g. http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/29/multiple-area-charts-with-d3-js/

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I've seen that but it doesn't implement what I desire. Namel, they are all on separate charts. The question in the OP is how to change that graph so that the areas are combined, or, to put it another way, What is it about the chart in the OP that keeps the areas separate? The link you provided doesn't answer that, but thank you anyways.

Comment: Ok, then I really don't understand what you mean. Do you mean something like http://projects.delimited.io/experiments/multi-series/stacked-area-full.html, described on http://www.delimited.io/blog/2014/3/3/creating-multi-series-charts-in-d3-lines-bars-area-and-streamgraphs ?

Comment: no, that's like the one I linked to in the OP. I basically want this, http://projects.delimited.io/experiments/multi-series/multi-line.html but with the area filled in under each of them

Comment: So all you'd need to do is replace `d3.svg.line` with `d3.svg.area` and set the value for y0 to 0 always.

Comment: thanks, that sort of works, but when I tried a demo with one area the coloring is inverted i.e. everywhere that's NOT part of the area is blue, and the area itself is white. It should be the opposite. I have set y0 to 0

Comment: o, sorry, I tried setting y0 to 0 with my own demo. Did you mean do that with the blog demo? ok, I'll try it and report back.

Comment: Sorry, I mean logical 0 (i.e. the bottom of the graph). See http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/da32c1afbe9aa1371ecf